# Compare user attributes in template using IF statement

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have a list of users and want to display their tasks only if the selected user belongs to the same department. My Models have a department field that I want to compare. 
This is my template code.

```
{% extends 'view_users.html' %}
{% block view_user_tasks %}
    <a href="{% url 'view_users' %}"> Back</a>
    <p> todo lists for {{ user }}</p>
      {% for todo in view_user_tasks %}
      <a href="{% url 'detail' todo.id %}" id="left_pencil"></a>
      <a id="{{todo.id}}" class="todo_remove"></a>
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock view_user_tasks %}
```

What i want to do is evaluate this condition:

```
if request.user.Department == user.Department:
    show user tasks
```

This are my respective views.

```
class ViewUsers(ListView):
    model = CustomUser
    template_name = 'view_users.html'

class ViewUserTasks(ListView):
    model = Todo
    template_name = 'view_user_tasks.html'
    context_object_name = 'view_user_tasks'
```

My models.py

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser)
    id = HashidAutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s: %s" % (self.title, self.body)
```

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    Department = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

How can I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Add your models to the questions

Comment: Added the models @gdef_

Answer (score 2):

Do your filtering logic in the view. You can override the default `get_queryset` method and return only the Todos that you want.

```
class ViewUserTasks(ListView):
    template_name = 'view_user_tasks.html'
    context_object_name = 'view_user_tasks'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Todo.objects.filter(user__Department=self.request.user.Department)
```

And then just loop through the returned data like you are already doing.

Comment: When i add that line am getting this error ```Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: body, checked, created_at, id, owner, title```

Comment: Where is the model with the `Department` that you mention in your question? Is that the `CustomUser` model linked by owner?

Comment: Try with `Todo.objects.filter(owner__Department=self.request.user.Department)`

Comment: The filter works. I can only see tasks by people in my department. However it shows all tasks made by all people in my department. How can i filter to ensure that when I click on a name (user1), only tasks by user1 are shown if he is a member of my department?

Comment: Isnt that what you were looking for? If you want to show the ones specific to the users you can do that by removing the Department part. `Todo.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)`

Comment: Assuming we have 4 users, user1(Finance), user2(Finance), user3(Finance), user4(HR). Am logged in as user1. When I click on user2 I should be able to see a list of their tasks. Same with user3 because they are both members of my department (Finance), but when I click on user4 I should be unable to view their tasks because they are in a different department (HR)

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand your question, you can compare it like this:

```
{% if todo.user.id == user.id %}
```

Comment: I want to click on view user tasks and only get their tasks if the user belongs to the  same department as me(logged in user).